# Explanation of $d^{-1}$ in modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I wasnt quite sure what to name this question, so that's what it is.

I'me working on an encryption system, and I need modulus. I already asked a question on this, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627365/define-in-this-situation), and I cannot figure out the answer to this, and I was hoping someone could explain it a little better for me? I said that it made sense, because it seemed to, but then I realized I was doing it wrong and it was too late -_-

How does d = $d^{-1} = 103$ BECAUSE $103 \cdot 7 = 721$ and $721 ≡ 1 \pmod{ 120}$?

I understand that $721 ≡ 1 \pmod {120}$ is $6$ remainder $0$, but how does that justify that $d^{-1} = 103$? and in the second part, $103 \times 7$, why is it $\times 7$?

Any help would be appreciated! Please explain this like talking to a ten year old :D

Comment: You should not have accepted the answer to your prior question if you did not understand it. This question is essentially a duplicate of the prior one. Instead, you should edit the prior question and/or use comments to ask for further elaboration on prior answers.

Comment: Dear @BillDubuque : That question seems to be "what does congruence mean?" and this one seems to be "what does inverse mean in congruences?" While I appreciate your frustration with hasty questions, I think we should make sure duplicates match. Regards

Comment: That said, this might be a super-duplicate of some other question, in which case, close away. It does not sound new to me.

Comment: @rschwieb It seems to me to be the same question as here - read the OPs comments to the answer. Actually theere seems to be a number of points that need clarification, not only what modular inverses are, but also the difference between mod as a relation vs. operator. These were adsressed (briefly) in comments.

Comment: Dear @BillDubuque : I think the button says "duplicate question" not "displays similar misunderstanding in the comments of a nonduplicate." In fact, I should think a lot of comments in other answers lead to legitimate new posts.

Comment: @rschwieb But the misunderstandings are already in the prior question, They OP simply did not make it clear where they were. Both were already addressed in a discussion in comments to the prior answer. If new questions are posed everytime something like this occurs, it will lead to combinatorial explosion. Better to edit the question to clarify where the confusion lies.

Comment: Remark that one way to test duplicity is to see if the new question receives answers that are (essentially) duplicates of answers to the original. That is precisely what happened here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the inverse of a real number. Well...given $x$ the inverse of a real number is the number we will call $x^{-1}$ and has the following property:

$x \times x^{-1} = 1$

Okay...nothing changes in this definition when we go to modulus. If we take $d = 7$ (in mod 120), what is its inverse? It's the number that when multiplied by 7 will give us 1 as an answer. In fact:

$7 \times 103 = 721 = 1 \text{ }(mod\text{ } 120)$

So we have it! We must accept (by the definition of the inverse) that $d^{-1} = 103$, as "strange" as this may seems.

Now...can you prove that when you are dealing with prime number as the module each number will have its inverse?

Comment: so what you're saying is that 720 = mod 120? because 720/120 = remainder of 0? so then 721 = 1 mod 120 as an inverse because it has a remainder of 1? is that what the "1" in 1 (mod 120) stands for?

Comment: Yes, that is it...anything that in "normal arithmetic" has a remainder 1 when divided by 120 **IS** 1 when you are usind mod 120.

Comment: ok, so what happens if we just do 721 = mod 120 instead of 721 = 1 mod 120?

Comment: If you don't get it, try thinking in terms of "clock arithmetic". If it is 8 o'clock, and 4 hours pass (8+4), what time is it? 1 o'clock, so 8 + 4 = 1.

And if you let 2 intervals of 8 hours pass, starting at noon (8 $\times$ 2), what time will be it? 4 o'clock, so 8 $\times$ 2 = 4.

It's always the same thing, you only change how many hours "fit" in the clock...

Comment: What is 721 = mod 120? Equal is not an operation, it's a statement... That is like saying "What if I do 3 = ?"

Comment: OH! so the 721 = 1 is its own thing, mod 120 is like saying "solve x + c = 6 given c = 4" where mod 120 is the given statement?

Comment: mod 120 is just to remember that we are in a "120 hours clock", that we will lap back to 0 when we get to 720. I don't think you comparison is exactly valid...you aren't solving for anything. They simply are the same thing. In a "120 hours clock" the number 721 will lap 6 times and get back to 1 o'clock, so 721 = 1 (mod 120)

Comment: yeah sorry thats what i meant XD so its a statement, plus a reminder. so 721 = 1. thats what it is, but its because we're doing mod 120? my wording may suck but i hope you get what i'm asking?

Comment: Yes...of course! If you change the module it will change how many times you lap and get a different result. For instance 721 = 6 in module 11, because you will "lap" 65 times and go back to 6

Comment: oh ok... so because 721 / 11 = 65.54545454545454, you take the first digit in the answer and thats the result?

Comment: No...it's the remainder in a simple integer division...721/11 = 65 (remainder 6). You lap 65 times and go 6 further...It has nothing to do with the first digit of the division, that was just an unfortunate coincidence

Comment: ahhhh ok. yeah i dont know why i didnt try that first! thank you VERY much sir/madam! you have helped me greatly :)

Comment: Try proving that every number (except 0) has an inverse if you are dealing in a prime module. For instance: 1,2,3,4,5,6 all have inverses in module 7. Try to understand why the same won't happen with 1,2,3,4,5 in module 6. I think that is a good starting point, once you get the concepts of modular arithmetic

Answer (score 4):

The [multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) of $x$ is, by definition, another thing $x^{-1}$ such that $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x=1$.

This definition works in the context of modular arithmetic, with modular multiplication.

According to this definition, $103\cdot 7=1\pmod {120}$ implies that $103=7^{-1}$ and $7=103^{-1}$.

While $7\cdot 103=721$ in *integer* multiplication, modular arithmetic mod 120 says that every multiple of $120$ is "the same thing as zero." So, $720=6\cdot 120=6\cdot 0$ is the same thing as zero, and $1+720$ is the same thing as $1$ mod $120$.

Comment: so 721 = 1 mod 120 is 1? that's why it is the answer to the inverse of d?

Comment: No, "$721=1 \pmod{ 120}$" is not any number, not even 1. We're saying "721 is 1". Since $103\cdot 7=721$, we can then conclude that $103\cdot 7=1$. When a pair of numbers multiplies to the identity like this, we say that they are inverses of each other. I don't know what you have in mind by $d$. From the context I gathered that it was $7$.

Comment: ugg! i'm getting quite frusturated. i feel like what you're saying makes sense, but for whatever reason I just cant get it...

Comment: @PulsePanda I think you need to spend a few minutes deciding exactly what your question is. Do you not understand what an inverse is? Do you not understand what equality in modular arithmetic means?

Comment: i understand inverse, interger wise, such as 2 * 0.5 = 1; thus 0.5 is the inverse of 2. but the whole mod thing is throwing me off.

Comment: @PulsePanda Well these inverses work the same way as rational numbers, it's just that equality is different. $1=121=241=-119$ etc, when you are working mod $120$.